# Make a list of posts with a tag in Markdown and Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll

How do I make a list of posts with a tag in Markdown and Jekyll? What I am trying to find is some how to change the following code:

```
<ul class="posts">
{% for post in site.posts limit: 20 %}
  <div class="post_info">
    <li>
         <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a> 
         <span>({{ post.date | date:"%Y-%m-%d" }})</span>
    </li>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

To only show posts with the tag "**question**"?  Can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

user1177636's method should work, but there's a simpler one:

```
<ul class="posts">
{% for post in site.tags.question limit: 20 %}
  <div class="post_info">
    <li>
         <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
         <span>({{ post.date | date:"%Y-%m-%d" }})</span>
    </li>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This way, Jekyll does most of the work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation:

```
<ul class="posts">
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.tags contains 'question' %}
    {% if count < 20 %}
      {% assign count = count|plus:1 %}
      <div class="post_info">
        <li>
          <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
          <span>({{ post.date | date:"%Y-%m-%d" }})</span>
        </li>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Newer versions of liquid also have `{% break %}` and `{% continue %}` constructs, so you can now break out of that loop when your counter hits 20. :)